# Pull multiple image from database and display them in thumbnail format using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I would just like to know how this is done.

Here is the html code , now when I pull this info from the database to display like
thumbnails. how do incorporate php into it in order to show the same results. This thumbnail gallery when you hover over the picture it makes the picture larger

Basically i am confused on how to display the pics from database into the below html code in order to get the same results that the code would provide when using jquery.

```
<div id ="thumbnail_pics">

<ul>
        <li class="thumb"><a href="1.jpg" class="preview" title="Bathroom"><img src="1s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a></li>
        <li class="thumb"><a href="2.jpg" class="preview" title="Pool"><img src="2s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a></li>
        <li class="thumb"><a href="3.jpg" class="preview" title="Kitchen"><img src="3s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a></li>
        <li class="thumb"><a href="4.jpg" class="preview" title="Main Bedroom"><img src="4s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a></li>
</ul>

</div>  <!-- Thumbnail   end  !-->
```

I have not done the database yet, i just would like an example of how this done done please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would query the database then use a loop to display the results in the format of your choice. I assume you know how to connect to the database, so see the link below for an example of a database query and loop using PHP PDO.

https://www.php.net/pdo.query#refsect1-pdo.query-examples

Comment: yes i do know how to connect but, can you give me an example? of how i would do this? Cant i just echo those images out within the img tag of the above ? to display them once i retrieve them from database . I am new to php therefor not using pdo currently

Comment: You would normally store the file names in the database and echo the filename, you could obviously prepend this with the rest of the path to the file. For example `<img src="<?php echo $row['filename']" alt="gallery thumbnail" />`